# Ruby each and collect change array of arrays

Tags: ruby

I expected that Array.each and Array.collect would never change an object, like in this example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.each { |x| x = 5 }
a #output => [1, 2, 3]
```

But this doesn't seem to be the case when you are working with an array of arrays or an array of hashes:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20], ["a"]]
a.each { |x| x[0]=5 }
a #output => [[5, 2, 3], [5, 20], [5]]
```

Is this behaviour expected or am I doing something wrong?

Doesn't this make ruby behaviour a little unexpected? For example, in C++ if a function argument is declared const, one can be confident the function won't mess with it (ok, it can be mutable, but you got the point).

Comment: You are experiencing the same behavior as this: `a = [[1]]`, `b = a.dup # => [[1]]`, `b[0][0] = 2 #=> [[2]]`, `a #=> [[2]]`. `dup` makes a "shallow" copy of `a`, whereas you were expecting a "deep" copy.  Many sources explain this distinction in greater detail and explain ways of making a "deep" copy.  [This](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/deepcopy.htm) is one.

Comment: @CarySwoveland very correct.. `#each` passes the value to the block using *deep copy*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `each` or `map` does not change the array itself. But is might look like it changes elements in the array. In fact when a array is holding references to other object, that references are keep unchanged, but the referenced object itself can change. I agree it is surprising when you learn it.

What you noticed:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a.each { |x| x[0] = 'x' }
puts a    # => ['x', 'x', 'x']
```

Here the first array element still references the same string, but the string has change.

Why it is important to understand this references?

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a = array
b = array
puts b # => ['a', 'b', 'c']
a[0] = 'x'
puts b # => ['x', 'b', 'c']
```

Does `freeze` protect us from changes?

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c'].freeze
a << ['d'] # throws 'can't modify frozen Array (RuntimeError)'
```

Seems so. But again only for the array itself. It does not deep freeze the array.

```
a[0][0] = 'x'
puts a.inspect ['x', 'b', 'c']
```

I suggest the read about topics like referenced objects, pointers, call by value vs. call by reference.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20], ["a"]]
a.each { |x| x[0]=5 }
```

In the above example, `x` is an `array` ( which you are passing to the block in each iteration ), from which you are accessing an element from its `0th` index, and updating it. As array is *mutable object*, it also updating. Here `a` is an array of array.

In *1<sup>st</sup>* iteration `x` is `[1, 2, 3]`. Now you are calling, `Array#[]=` method to update the *0<sup>th</sup>* element of `[1, 2, 3]`.

In *2<sup>nd</sup>* iteration `x` is `[10, 20]`. same as above.

..and so on.. Thus after `#each` has completed its iterations, you got modified `a`.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.each { |x| x = 5 }
```

In the above example, you are passing the array element to the each block, which are *Fixnum* object, and not mutable also. Here `a` ia an array of elements, and you are just accessing those elements.

**update ( to clear OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087720/random-user) )**

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20], ["a"]]
a.each do |x|
  # here x is holding the object from the source array `a`.
  x # => [1, 2, 3]
  x.object_id # => 72635790
  # here you assgined a new array object, which has the same content as the
  # inner array element [1, 2, 3]. But strictly these are 2 different object. Check
  # out the object_id of those two.
  x = [1, 2, 3]
  x # => [1, 2, 3]
  x.object_id # => 72635250
  break # used break to stop iteration after 1st one.
end
```

Comment: thanks, still I find this unexpected like in `a = [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20], ["a"]]; a.each { |x| x=[1,2,3]; x[0]=5 }`

Comment: @random_user well. Now in the example, you have given in the comment, you are defining a new *array* object and assigned to `x`. Although both the *array has same elements*, they are not same object.